# How to find orthogonal eigenvectors if some of the eigenvalues are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an example:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 4 & 8 & 17 \end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalue I found is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_3=22$.
For $\lambda=1$, 
$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -2\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}y+\begin{pmatrix} -4\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}z$$
For $\lambda=22$,
$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1/4\\ 1/2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}z$$
However, those eigenvectors I found are not orthogonal to each other. The goal is to find an orthogonal matrix P and diagonal matrix Q so that $A=PQP^T$.

Comment: Not every matrix is diagonalizable (I'm responding to your last sentence, last paragraph).

Comment: @stressedout Yes, I do know that. I mean in this problem I need to find the corresponding P and Q matrix

Comment: @stressed out: This is a real symmetric matrix. Those are always diagonalizable, and we can always choose orthogonal eigenvectors.

Comment: @jmerry  That's right. I didn't check the matrix to see that it's symmetric.

Comment: Here's a possible solution: $A$ is symmetric and you have two distinct eigenvalues. So, you get two orthogonal eigenvectors. Since your vectors are $3$-dimensional, get the third one using cross-product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing we know is that eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. So, if we find eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ for $\lambda_1< \lambda_2< \lambda_3$ we are done. On the other hand, we have eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_3=22$, so that there are not $3$ distinct eigenvalues and the situation becomes somewhat more complicated.

Suppose we found $v_1,v_2\in E(A,\lambda_1)$ which are linearly independent (and hence a basis for the Eigenspace). We know that $v_1\perp v_3$ and $v_2\perp v_3$. This means $\langle v_1,v_3\rangle=\langle v_2,v_3\rangle=0$. By bilinearity of the inner product, we get that $\langle av_1+bv_2,v_3\rangle =0$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. The upshot is that the entire eigenspace $E(A,\lambda_1)$ is orthogonal to $v_3$. So, we are free to choose *any* basis of eigenvectors for $E(A,\lambda_1)$ and proceed from there. Well, just apply Gram-Schmidt to $v_1,v_2$. Define 
$$ u_1=\frac{v_1}{\lVert v_1\rVert}$$
$$ u_2=\frac{v_2-\langle v_2, u_1\rangle u_1}{\lVert v_2-\langle v_2, u_1\rangle u_1\rVert}.$$
A quick check shows that these two vectors form an orthonormal basis for $E(A,\lambda_1)$. Then, if we take any nonzero $v_3\in E(A,\lambda_3)$ and set 
$$ u_3=\frac{v_3}{\lVert v_3\rVert}$$
we can see that $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$is an orthonormal eigenbasis of $\mathbb{R}^3\cong E(\lambda_1,A)\oplus E(\lambda_3,A)$ with respect to $A$. You've already found the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Once you compute $u_1,u_2,u_3$, the matrix $P=[u_1,u_2,u_3]$ is orthogonal and 
$$
A=P^T
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&22
\end{bmatrix}
P.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal. You have two different eigenvalues, hence you have two orthogonal eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Since your matrix is $3\times 3$, the third vector to form $P=[v_1 | v_2 |v_3]$ has to be $v_3=\pm v_1\times v_2$. It is easy to see that $PP^T=I$.

Now just take $Q=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ and solve $A=PQP^T$ to determine $Q$ completely and then you're done.

Answer (score 0):

How about Gram-Schmidt?   Since the eigenspace is $2$-dimensional,  there are certainly $2$ such.

Project and subtract:  $(-4,0,1)-8\frac15(-2,1,0)= (-\frac45,-\frac85,1)$.

Now normalize:  $\frac5{23}(-\frac45,-\frac85,1)=(-\frac4{23},-\frac8{23},\frac5{23}):=b_1$.  And $(-\frac2{\sqrt5},\frac1{\sqrt5},0):=b_2$.

Finally,  normalize the eigenvector for $\lambda =22$:
$\frac{16}{21}(\frac14,\frac12,1)=(\frac4{21},\frac8{21},\frac{16}{21}):=b_3$.  Conveniently, this one is orthogonal to the others by symmetry of the matrix.

(Alternatively,  the cross-product would have been a good way to do this as well.)

Finally,  the matrix  $P$ whose columns are the basis vectors, $b_1,b_2,b_3$, above will do the trick:  $P^tAP=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&22\end{pmatrix}$.